# How to access and filter groups in JWT token using Azure AD?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

net core application. I am returning JWT token which returns all the groups. I have below configuration in manifest.

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
    "optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [
            {
                "name": "groups",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }
        ]
    },
```

Currently users has 100 or 200 groups. So I want to return groups via graph api. Along with that I want to return only groups whose name starts with AP. May I know is this possible? Any help in this regard appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently not possible.
If users have more than 200 groups, they won't be in the token.
In those cases you have to query for the group memberships via Graph API.

If you only have few groups that you care about, you can query for the members of those groups and see if the user is in them.
Depends a bit on the data if it is faster to get the user's groups or to get the members of the groups you care about.

You can also assign users/groups to roles in your application, if that is the purpose of these checks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If i want to access groups through graph api then I know the url to get groups. Is it possible to include like this"accessToken": [
   {
    "name": "groups",
    "source": "https://graph.windows.net/KmartAus.onmicrosoft.com/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,'ap')",
    "essential": false,
    "additionalProperties": []
   }

Comment: If I am getting groups through Graph API, then I need to implement this separately in my code? also is it possible to get group name as an option inside token if there is smaller number of groups exists? Also i heard now Microsoft has restricted to only 5 groups and few article says 200. so which is correct?

Comment: The smaller restriction could be for roles or when acquiring token with implicit grant flow. Names you cannot get in token.

Comment: If I am trying to return only 50 groups in my token without graph api then in this case is there any way to filter out the groups for example group name starts with ap something?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It's all security groups or nothing

Comment: Okay thanks Is it possible to get group name in token in any way?

Comment: Not that I know of :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199904/discussion-between-niranjan-and-juunas).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the associated enterprise app registration to filter groups that will be included in the claim.
[Group Filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#group-filtering)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32251019)